# How to parse raw file extracted from system/bin/fb0 to .png file in android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, screenshot, framebuffer, android-screen

I know this is question was already asked on stack overflow, but none were helped. Basically i wanted to extract screenshot of another app programatically, for which i managed to get raw formatted image from dev/graphics/fb0 from my rooted device. When i opened this image, it looked as shown below.

I would be thankful if someone could provide, solution which would convert this raw image into .PNG format.

[image]

Above image is screen shot of this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had converted the raw image into png using imagemagick
->installed image magick 
->from that i have taken convert exe file [ renamed as convertim]and placed inside C drive Windows folder

### Enter the following Command in command prompt

convertim -depth 8 -size 480x272 rgba:C:\Test\rawimagename.raw -separate -swap 0,2 -combine C:\Test\mockimage.png

480x272  ( resolution )
 -depth 8 ( changes depends on the resolution)